# R Applying a formular using a factor over a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like some help on how to run formulas over several variables and based on factors, so an example based on hourly data for a week:

```
df<- data.frame(a = runif(168),
+               b = runif(168),
+               c = runif(168),
+               d = rep(1:7, each = 24))

attach(df)

fx<-function(x) { mean(x) } # it can be more complicated, just to illustrate
```

a, b, c are different variables, d is my factor.

Here I have a made a factor for each day and I would like apply it over all 3 variables, and write each result into a seperate vector/dataframe. So, what im doing now is:

```
a.mean <-tapply(a, d, fx)
b.mean <-tapply(b, d, fx)
c.mean <-tapply(c, d, fx)
```

Which makes me pretty sure there are some neat tricks I've missed but can't seem to find. I would like to be able to drop the factor variable and just loop over specified periods and over as many variables as I would like to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using formula interface to `aggregate`, the dot (`.`) can be used to represent all other variables:

```
aggregate(.~d, df, mean)
  d         a         b         c
1 1 0.5444300 0.4348559 0.5543393
2 2 0.5997199 0.4751082 0.5116904
3 3 0.4195746 0.6696669 0.5239728
4 4 0.4764139 0.5102245 0.4901829
5 5 0.3938329 0.3792583 0.4826971
6 6 0.4633260 0.5518397 0.4558116
7 7 0.4814347 0.4946845 0.5371871
```

Note that you don't need to attach the data.frame using this either (as it is supplied to `aggregate` as a parameter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use plyr package for that (where mydata is your data):

```
 library(plyr)
 ddply(mydata,.(d), summarise, meana=mean(a),meanb=mean(b), meanc=mean(c))
```

or just use this:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydata,.(d), colwise(mean))
```