# R Regression: referring to multiple independent variables simultaneously

Tags: r, indexing, regression

I would like to run a regression on a set of variables without actually specifying the names of the variables themselves.

For example, given the data frame:

```
data(iris)
iris=iris
```

Instead of running:

```
lm(formula = (Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width), data=iris)
```

I would like to specify the independent variables all at once without naming them. Hopefully, this would look something like:

```
lm(formula = (Sepal.Length ~ iris[, 2:4], data=iris)
```

R has to have some functionality that allows me to do this, but despite extensive experimentation I haven't been able to suss it out.

Comment: Those are the "independent variables". Do this: `lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., iris[-5])`

Comment: The strategy to use the 'dot' method described in `?formula` is not limited to regression formulas. My close vote is based on an answer to a formula used in `aggregate`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533830/r-applying-a-formular-using-a-factor-over-a-data-frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `.` to replace all the rest of regressors:

```
> lm(Sepal.Length ~ ., data=iris[, -5])
```